# Which HTTP Errors Should Be Custom Handled?

Tags: asp.net, http, error-handling, user-interface

In my web site, I am currently custom handling two HTTP errors: 404 Not Found and 403 Forbidden.  This "handling" consists of redirecting the user to a custom error page specific to the particular error.  Are there any other HTTP (or, in fact, other kinds) errors that occur often enough to warrant a custom redirect and page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be relatively thorough, you can consider handling these two:

- **401: Unauthorized.** You didn't recognize the login attempt. (Contrast with 403, where they do authenticate successfully but don't have permission to see the resource they asked for.)
- **500: Server Error.** Something went wrong server-side and you couldn't recover from it.

If you expect to get a lot of traffic, perhaps also consider handling 503:

- **503: Service Unavailable.** The server got your request but is too busy to handle it right now.

Comment: I've always been nervous about custom handling of 401 since it is used to trigger authentication via WWW-Authenticate. Though the RFC does recommend that the user agent present the content if authentication was attempted previously so it might make sense.

Answer (score 2):

I would handle the 500 error page to be more friendly, like Stackoverflow does: https://stackoverflow.com/error

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ruby on rails and by default it helps you handling these:

- **404**: Not found
- **422**: Unprocessable Entity
- **500**: Server error

I then usually add handling for **403**: Forbdiden